# Adding a website URL to a Profile Field

Tags: uri

Adding a users' website link (URL) to a field.
Can somebody please clarify the best approach to this using Profile2 as I cannot seem to find any option for "URL" type in any field. Maybe I'm having a blond moment or just cannot see the wood for the trees, but to save us hours searching online, can somebody advise on the simplest and most obvious solution to users being able to enter their 'website' link (ie: to link to an external URL such as a homesite such as a bandname.com, mybusiness.com).

I am also using Field Collection but presume any created filed type will be similar in setup.

I would envisage the user being able to add such a URL into their profile detial post registration in a similar way to the user DB on drupal.org (ala "Mywebsite").

Thank you.

Comment: did you tried http://drupal.org/project/link?

Comment: Thank you Mohammad, I've replied to Clive below, but a verbatim answer to you also for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native URL field type in Drupal 7 but the [Link module](http://drupal.org/project/link/) provides one with lots of features

> With this module links can be added easily to any content types and profiles and include advanced validating and different ways of storing internal or external links and URLs.

Profile2 profiles are entities so adding a link field to one will be an easy task through the UI.

Comment: Thank you Clive, looks like Link Module will be the one, (seems I missed that in my drupal.org search) I shall look into it now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Excellent! For those who require to add a "Users" external website URL with a User Profile, this is the module. Hopefully this will be included in any future D8 core (-:

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve that using the [URL field](https://www.drupal.org/project/url) module. I've used this module in one of my project. You can also add Optional title field to the URL.

Image from the module page.
[image]

---

You can also achieve that without using any contributed module.

Add textarea field (instead of text filed) and set Text processing  as *Filtered text* in the field settings. Make sure to select  **Convert URLs into links** option in Text Formats.

That's it. The entered URL will be appeared as link at output.

Comment: Thanks very much for your tip, I will checkout the Module to see if I can reuse it in my future projects, I'll let you know how I get on and feedback where appropriate. (-: